# How can i inject a bean into global velocity context in spring boot & spring mvc

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, velocity

I am developing a website with spring boot, spring mvc and velocity, the question is How can i inject a bean such as `User` into **global** velocity context, and then i can use `$User.getName()` or `$User.address` in the global velocity templates(header.vm)?

Note1:  **global velocity context** , not the individual request where i can inject objects by Model/ModelAndView etc.

Note2: i have tried the annotation `@DefaultKey("User")`, but not work, maybe other configurations required?

Comment: dependencies concerning velocity :  velocity 1.7, velocity-tools 2.0 spring-context-support 4.3.5 RELEASE

Comment: Could you provide your current code, configuration, etc?

Comment: Have you tried registering the data in the ServletContext? I think that you can access it using $application. But it seems that what you need is to register the data in the session.